# Change all wordpress image links to new host

Tags: jquery, regex, wordpress

I am running wordpress and I just placed all my images to point to my cloudfront cdn. But I realized that it is not an sound investment, so I revert back to just pointing my images to my amazon s3 link.

But what about those previous posts that is pointed to my cdn. Is there a way to change them?

The solution I thought is using JQuery on document ready. I'm not sure if this will solve it.  We know js scripts has a sort of delay so images would had loaded before the script change it.

The best solution I know is using regex, but I am unfamiliar on how the formatting works.

To sum it up I want:

From

```
<img src="http://previous.link.com/image.jpg"/>
```

To

```
<img src="http://new.link.com/image.jpg" />
```

Will using Jquery suffient? if not, can anyone provide a direction on how to do this?

Comment: Can you not simply edit the previous posts, or perhaps form a MySQL query to change from one host to the other? (I don't know *how*, with MySQL, but it seems a better idea to do this once, rather than *every time* one of those previous pages loads.)

Comment: @DavidThomas I can't edit them manually if they're over a 100 posts.

Comment: I didn't say it'd be easy; just that it would be the better approach: cure the disease, don't keep treating the symptoms.

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery (or Javascript in general) to solve this is just a dirty hack.

I assume you have access to the server? If so, alter the database directly.

It's not very hard, there is a free tool: [phpMyAdmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php), you can then run your MySQL query

Just make sure to back-up the database before any work.

Answer (score 0):

You have to search and replace those  strings within your Wordpress Database.

Assuming your images part of your post content you can try the [Search and Replace Plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search-and-replace/) by Frank Bueltge.

This Plugin allows you to search and replace any string in the following Tables:

- ID
- post-content
- GUID
- titel
- excerpt
- meta-data
- comments
- comment-author
- comment-e-mail
- comment-url
- tags/categories
- categories-description

Or you could try tools like phpMyAdmin to solve your issue.

jQuery is, depending on the count of images, not really an option!

Comment: I find the plugin ... risky. I just want to replace the ones in the _post, but it wants me to replace postmeta and options as well.

Comment: Dangerous? You're able to define exactly which tables should be searched. http://s.wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search-and-replace/screenshot-1.png?r=550931

Comment: Make an Datebase Backup first! Then search for src="http://previous.link.com/ and replace it with src="http://new.link.com/

Comment: phpMyAdmin: 1.Choose your Datebase, 2.Choose your Table. 3. Choose the SQL Tab and paste your Query into that field :)